What does retry in SparkUI means?
I have spark executed in two different instances:

spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled=false
spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled=true

In the first instance, the stage graphs have some retries and the other one doesn't.
Can you help me understand what retry means here and why is it performing the extra data shuffle?
First:

Second:


I would recommend you to go to SQL tab in Spark UI, there is checkbox show Stage ID (check it)
and see what stages were doing which job,
this way, you can compare 1st and 2nd approaches and see what was added extra in 1st (e.g. additional shuffle operations (Exchange) etc)

btw, in 2nd screen there Skipped stages
it most likely means that they were cached by previous job, that is why you see only 3 stages instead of 6 in 2nd approach

What does retry mean?
It most likely means that some task within stage failed, was retried and succeeded
why the extra data shuffle it is doing?
In second screen you have 3 skipped stages
It normally means that they were cached, and that is why they were not re-executed
Do you use .cache anywhere?

What does retry mean here?

It simply indicates that a task in Spark encountered an error during its execution and Spark automatically retries it a few times before giving up.

You can configure it via spark.task.maxFailures parameter, default is 4.

Why is it performing the extra data shuffle?
Now, as mentioned in the Spark SQL performance tuning guide for spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled:

When true and spark.sql.adaptive.enabled is true, Spark will coalesce contiguous shuffle partitions according to the target size (specified by spark.sql.adaptive.advisoryPartitionSizeInBytes), to avoid too many small tasks.

It hints that in your case this optimized coalescing is not happening and this may be causing uneven data distribution, increasing the likelihood of task failures and retries.
And the same might be the reason for extra data shuffling as well. It's possible that when the adaptive partitioning is off - spark.sql.shuffle.partitions takes over and the default value 200 might not be fit for your datasets. And causing data locality issues and ultimately the issues you are facing.
